# What is the POST variable for "password" for Twilio SMS sevice via cURL?

Tags: http, curl, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am trying to do a simple cURL call to send very few text messages. I do NOT want to use the Twilio helper library.

My problem: However I try sending the  - password / sid / authentificationCode  -  I get an error message `"Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect.", "message": "Authentication Error - No password provided"`.

Twilio gives this example ([here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133907-Simple-Example-for-Sending-Programmable-SMS-Text-or-Picture-Messages)):

```
  curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json \
--data-urlencode "To=+13105555555" \
--data-urlencode "From=+12125551234" \
--data-urlencode "MediaUrl=https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png" \
--data-urlencode "Body=Hello from my Twilio line!" \
-u 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token'
```

I want to launch this as a script. My problem is passing over the password.

I have:

```
$twilioID = "AC7cXXXXXXXXXXXXXb";
$twilioAuthToken = "4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2";
$twilioUkNumber = "+44XXXXX471";

$url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC7c622XXXXXXXXXXX9d7c84e1b/Messages.json";

$postData=array(
    "to"=>"+44XXXXXXXXX",
  "from"=>$twilioUkNumber,
  "sid"=>$twilioAuthToken,
  "body"=> "If this doesn't work I will kill someone!"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD , $twilioAuthToken); ((See below))

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$curlOutput=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Reading up on cURL I substituted `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD , $twilioAuthToken)` for `-u 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token'` but that does not work nor does "sid" nor "password" as the POST variable name.

Does anyone know what it is or is it impossible to go this route? (And just to be clear I do NOT want to carry on with the helper library!)

Answer (score 0):

Well did not find the POST variable but the work around is:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD ,"$twilioID:$twilioAuthToken")

I did not see it was BOTH id and AuthToken!